# How do I set my mac to ask what disc I want to boot from without having to hold alt?

Tags: startup

I can switch between OSX, Windows and a network drive, but I cannot seem to find this option anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

## [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/)

> rEFIt is a boot menu and maintenance toolkit for EFI-based machines like the Intel Macs. You can use it to boot multiple operating systems easily, including triple-boot setups with Boot Camp. It also provides an easy way to enter and explore the EFI pre-boot environment.

- rEFIt allows you to sync partition tables
- customize:

  - set default  to boot from
  - define wait time before a boot option is selected
  - configure the rEFIt boot screen

[image: http://macthemes.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=16802124]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/), which will automatically present you with all boot options when you install it to the OS X Volume (see [this article](http://refit.sourceforge.net/doc/c2s1_activate.html) for more detail).

Answer (score 0):

There's a System Preference pane called Startup Disk  (Apple > System Preferences > Startup Disk) that allows you to choose which disk to start up from.

Does that help any?

[image: Startup Disk Preference Pane]

Comment: This will not work in a multi-boot setup with linux operating systems.

Comment: This lets me select an OS, but not the option screen to choose what OS I want when the computer is switched on.